# How to send text message via bluetooth without using Editext and Button?

Tags: android, text, bluetooth, connect, send

if 2 device connect to eachother via Bluetooth one device work as Keyboard and other device work as a monitor.

if user can type in one device then it write in another device.

regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open keyboard then direct set text of key